# General inequality and infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, nested-radicals

I found the following problem on AoPS , and couldn't find a solution (and no headway whatsoever).

Show that  $a_n = \sqrt{1+\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}+\cdots +\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}}}} < (\pi)^{\frac{1}{e}}$.

And find $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{1+\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}+\cdots +\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}}}}$.

The first inequality is weak, and I have no idea how to proceed. I can't find a recurrence relation either.

Comment: Please expand your post to add more context. Where did these questions arise? Why are they of interest? Why do you suspect the values that you claim?  Also, please try to phrase your questions as request rather than demands ("Show that..." "And find..."). This is a site for people to ask questions about topics they are thinking about, rather than just posing problems. You can edit your post to improve it.

Comment: I got the problem from another forum,  where even after discussion,  nobody was able to solve the it.

Comment: Thanks - you could definitely say *which* other forum in this post, and include a link if possible. At the same time, you could explain why this problem is of interest. The mere fact that nobody has been able to solve a problem does not provide much context about why someone would want to solve the problem.

Comment: It was on AoPS, so I suspect it to be something like an Olympiad problem, though since I am not sure about the original source source, I didn't mention anything. I didn't include the link, since that particular post itself includes hundreds of questions and I feel that it would not help this question. http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c260h1242234p7039390. POST #1733

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if the limit (*let $a = \lim a_n$*) can be evaluated in closed form, though convergence is easily established and bounds can also be made as close as you desire.  Lower bounds are easy as $a_n$ is monotone increasing, successive $a_n$ give better lower bounds.

To find good upper bounds, we may borrow a trick often useful for nested radicals.  Note that from the well known limit (for $x> 0$):
$$f(x) = \sqrt{x+ \sqrt{x + \sqrt{x+\cdots }}} \implies f(x)=\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4x}}2$$

Hence for any $k>1$,
$$a = \sqrt{1+\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}+\cdots}}} < \sqrt{1+\sqrt{\frac12+\sqrt{\frac13+\cdots+\sqrt{\frac1k+f\left(\frac1{k+1} \right)}}}}$$

for our purposes $k=3$ suffices and gives 
$a < \sqrt{1+\sqrt{\frac12+\sqrt{\frac13+f\left(\frac14\right)}}} \implies a < 1.522998 <  \pi^{1/e} \approx 1.523671$